# Spring AoP - TransactionManager (tx:advice) and custom aspectJ weaved advice - Conflicting?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Been suffering through this all day, so I thought its time to turn to those more experienced than I.

My application uses Spring and Hibernate. Persistence through DAO objects.

App has Persistence and Business modules, with Business module depending on Persistence.

The DAOs obviously live in the persistence layer. My custom aspect lives in the Business layer.

In the persistence layer applicationContext.xml:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="create" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false" />
        <tx:method name="read" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="update" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false" />
        <tx:method name="delete" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false" />
        <tx:method name="executeFinder" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="executeLister" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="executeUpdate" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
       <aop:pointcut id="genericManagerMethods" expression="execution(public * foo.bar.dao.impl.GenericDaoHibernateImpl.*(..))" />
       <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="genericManagerMethods" />
</aop:config>
```

in the Business layer applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Activate aop weaving, currently only for provider resolving. -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="tenantAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<bean id="tenantAspect" class="foo.bar.aspects.ProviderAspect"/>
```

Finally, the ProviderAspect.java class:

```
@Aspect
public class ProviderAspect {

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VitalityProviderAspect.class);

@Before(value = "execution(* foo.bar.dao.impl.GenericDaoHibernateImpl.create(..))")
public void addTenantId(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("In the aspect!!")
}
```

Now for the weirdness....

In my integration tests, the test-applicationContext in the business module does NOT include the transaction advice. When my integration tests run, the AspectJ weaved advice gets applied appropriately. I therefore know my AspectJ config is correct.

When the project is then built and deployed (now using the full application-context) the AspectJ weaved advice seems to get ignored, and only the tx:advice gets applied. I dont even get shown any errors, it just doesn't seem to apply ProviderAspect. This also lets me believe that the transaction manager config has been set up correctly.

Could the two aspects be fighting/overwriting each other? How should this be avoided?

Comment: There is no weaving only proxies and this is the heart of your problem, you are probably creating a proxy of a proxy due to 2 different aop mechanism in play. Instead of writing your pointcut to the concrete class `GenericDaoHibernateImpl`, take the interface `GenericDao` instead. Something like `execution(* com.livingvitality.dao.GenericDao+.create(..))`.

Comment: OK - so if using two aspects on the same concrete class causes creation of a proxy of a proxy, then if i point them both to the interface, will they not inherently be proxying the instance of that type which will be the GenericDaoHibernateImpl ?

How is using multile advisors on the same class achieved generally?

Comment: It is not the fact that you use 2 aspects it is the fact of using `<aop:config />` together with `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`. Spring by default uses JDK dynamic proxies, which are interface based. A dynamic class is created implementing `GenericDao` but which isn't a `GenericDaoHibernateImpl` which results in a pointcut that will not match.